# Free DotnetNuke module for Forum Management

Tags: dotnetnuke

Can anybody please tell me where I will get free DNN module of forum,
I have downloaded YAF.DotNetNuke.Module for forum,
I installed it in DotNetNuke properly but it showing error while adding installed module on page that "YAF is currently Unavailable"

Please tell me another free DNN module for Forum management.

Thanks.

Comment: this is not a programming related question and doesn't really belong on stackoverflow.  You will get a much better response in the modules forum at dotnetnuke.com http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/199/scope/threads/Default.aspx

Comment: JitBit AspNetForums can also be integrated with DNN - [see here](http://www.jitbit.com/docs/asp-net-forum/!!!asp-net-forum-software-readme.htm)

Answer (score 0):

DNN has a core Forum module that is pretty decent.  http://dnnforum.codeplex.com/ There's a 5.0 RC that they just released